# Installed py2app missing icon as a different user

Tags: python, packagemaker, py2app

I'm using py2app and package maker to install a python program. The issue I'm having is that if I install as one user selecting 'install for all users' and then switch to a different user the icon for the app is missing- I just get a blank hole, but everything else works fine. I wondered if it was a permissions issue but the only `icns` file I can find in the package in `Contents/Resources` is 775. Is this the one that is used by the app?

It's hard to give a lot of information on this but hopefully someone has come across this before or has a suggestion as to why the icon might be missing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Was due to a corrupted plist file. After removing `~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.dock.plist` and logging in again it worked